# Javascript weird return statement instead of loop through array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I came across this javascript function:

```
function functionName(a, b) {
    return a[0]===b[0]&&a[1]===b[1]&&a[2]===b[2]&&a[3]===b[3]&&
           a[4]===b[4]&&a[5]===b[5]&&a[6]===b[6]&&a[7]===b[7]&&
           a[8]===b[8]&&a[9]===b[9]&&a[10]===b[10]&&a[11]===b[11]&&
           a[12]===b[12]&&a[13]===b[13]&&a[14]===b[14]&&a[15]===b[15];
};
```

I wonder in which situation would that code be better or faster than this (since a and b are obviously arrays of same length):

```
function functionName(a, b) {
    for( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
        if( a[i] !== b[i] ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

Or this version (if they are longer than 16):

```
function functionName(a, b) {
    for( var i = 0; i < 16; i++ ) {
        if( a[i] !== b[i] ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

Would appreciate any reference on this topic. Thanks.

Comment: (1) Just benchmark it. (2) It's rarely a good idea to second-guess the engine's optimizations.

Comment: well, both versions are pretty much the same. The only (dubious) optimisation you could do is modify the first one to be `for( var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++ ) {` other than that...don't think there is going to be much difference speed-wise

Comment: @Vid The `length` optimization has long been discredited as unnecessary. Let's stop spreading old wives' tales.

Comment: *since a and b are obviously arrays of same length*; no, they are both arrays with at least 16 elements. Either could have e.g. 18 elements.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan for that reason there is the second variation (if they are longer than 16). Yes you are right, maybe I should add "or they are longer and not the same length" but I kept it short and simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both versions do the same number of array element comparisons, I would expect the inline version to be faster as it does not have any of the loop management.  You can try this:

```js
var a = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true];
var b = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true];

function testA(a, b){
    return a[0]===b[0]&&a[1]===b[1]&&a[2]===b[2]&&a[3]===b[3]&&
           a[4]===b[4]&&a[5]===b[5]&&a[6]===b[6]&&a[7]===b[7]&&
           a[8]===b[8]&&a[9]===b[9]&&a[10]===b[10]&&a[11]===b[11]&&
           a[12]===b[12]&&a[13]===b[13]&&a[14]===b[14]&&a[15]===b[15];
}

function testB(a, b){
    for( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
      if( a[i] !== b[i] ) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}

var start;
var end;
var result;
var total;
var outerIttrations = 10;
var innerItterations = 1000 * 1000;

total = 0;
result = true;
for (var j=0; j<outerIttrations; j++){
    start = performance.now()
    for (var i=0; i< innerItterations; i++){ result = result && testA(a, b); }
    end = performance.now();
    total += (end - start);
}
console.log("Average Test A (inline) " + total / outerIttrations + " ("  + result + ")");

total = 0;
result = true;
for (var j=0; j<outerIttrations; j++){
    start = performance.now()
    for (var i=0; i< innerItterations; i++){ result = result && testB(a, b); }
    end = performance.now();
    total += (end - start);
}
console.log("Average Test B (loop) " + total / outerIttrations + " ("  + result + ")");
```